# Mapping a function over a multidimensional array in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I know there is a clean way to map a function `f:A => B` over an array, `foo` of type `Array[A]` to get an `Array[B]` via `foo.map{f}`.

Is there a clean way to map `f` over `bar:Array[Array[A]]` to get an `Array[Array[B]]` that preserves the array structure of `bar` while mapping all of the `A` elements to elements of type `B`?

In general, is there a way to map the elements of arrays of arbitrary dimensions (i.e. not just 2D but 3D, 4D, etc.).

Comment: This tempts me to write my own multi-dimensional array type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can map within the map:

```
bar.map(_.map(f))
```

<strike>I doubt there's a type-safe way to map arrays of arbitrary dimensions, since arrays of different dimensions are of different types.</strike> But it's simple enough to keep nesting map calls:

```
scala> val bam = new Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[A]]]]](0)
bam: Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[A]]]]] = Array()

scala> bam.map(_.map(_.map(_.map(_.map(f)))))
res1: Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[B]]]]] = Array()
```

Actually, I found that [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) has "generic map and fold operations over arbitrarily nested data structures". I haven't tested with `Array`, but it looks like it works with other data structures.

```
everywhere(f)(bam)
```

Comment: This shapeless project looks pretty cool, but it seems like overkill to install shapeless into my project for just this small use case. Any insight into how shapeless `everywhere(f)(bam)` works? Like what are the implicits you need?

Comment: One point to mention, I would expect that using shapeless to do this will incur a penalty in terms of compile-time, which increases as the depth increases; hence I wouldn't use this too much in your code. I'd also question the sense of your data structure in general (from a readability/maintenance perspective) - unless you are doing some scientific programming. In which case, you very possibly do not want to incur the runtime boxing overhead of using `map` on an `Array` (assuming that `A` is primitive).

Comment: @dsg I agree shapeless is overkill here, but you can easily create your own set of methods to map arrays of different dimensions, e.g. `def map2[A: Manifest, B: Manifest](a: Array[Array[A]])(f: A => B) = a map (_ map f)`. (Manifest is a context bound required specifically for Arrays.) You can't overload on type parameters, but you can create `map3`, `map4` etc that work with arrays of different dimensions.

Comment: also, body of `map3` could be simply `a map (map2(_)(f))`, and so on for higher dimensions

Comment: @dsg Agreed on the overkill part. But I was amazed by it all the same. Not sure which import you'll need; you'll have to check the source. For more details on how it works, check out [Scrap your boilerplate with class](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/gmap3.pdf).